# equivalency of the infinity norm and the $p = 1$ norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $||\vec{v}||_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$, which clearly is greater than $||\vec{v}||_{\infty} = max\{|x_i|\}$.

By definition, two norms $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ are equivalent if there exist constants $a, b$ such that:

$a||\cdot||_1 \leq ||\cdot||_2 \leq b||\cdot||_1$

We know in our case that:

$||\vec{v}||_{\infty} \leq ||\vec{v}||_1$

So set $b \geq 1$ and $a = \frac{1}{b}$ and we should be done.  Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

$|| \vec{\nu} ||_{1} \leq n || \vec{\nu}||_{\infty}$

Comment: Is what I did completely wrong?

Comment: In your general definition of norm equivalence, does $|| \cdot ||_{2}$ correspond to $|| \cdot ||_{\infty}$?  Otherwise, there is a notational ambiguity.  Because of this, I am not sure what you did.  Also, I am not seeing the inference that by setting $a  = 1/b$ we should be done.

However, your inequality $||\vec{v}||_{\infty} \leq ||\vec{v}||_1$ is correct, and together with the one I gave you it gives norm equivalence:
$$
|| \vec{\nu}||_{\infty} \leq || \vec{\nu} ||_{1} \leq n || \vec{\nu}||_{\infty}.
$$

Comment: $||\vec{v}||_{\infty} \leq ||\vec{v}||_1$ and thus $||\vec{v}||_{\infty} \leq b||\vec{v}||_1$ for all $b \geq 0$.  Then if I let $a = \frac{1}{b}$ I have the following: $\frac{1}{b}||\vec{v}||_1 \leq ||\vec{v}||_{\infty} \leq b||\vec{v}||_1$  Does that work if I switch the roles of the two norms?  If not, how can you justify the existence of the $n$ in your answer?

Comment: Please edit your last double inequality: it contains typos, and I can't understand it.

And, no, I don't see how you can switch the roles of the two norms.  If you start with $|\vec{v}||_{\infty} \leq b ||\vec{v}|_{1}|$ and divide both sides by $b$, you don't have the two norms switch roles.

Comment: I just did.  Hope my new comment makes more sense.

Comment: Your last double inequality still contains a typo: the first norm in it is unlabeled.

Comment: aaagghh I'm so stooopyd, sorry, I should not have asked this question in the first place.  hope none of my classmates see it :(

Comment: You can remove it if you want.